# PHP strpos array

Tags: php, arrays, strpos

I am trying to loop through a string that contains html from a scraped webpage. First I look to return all links that contain the word "result" and then I would like to organize all the links that contain one of four cases, "base", "second", "third" or "latest" and create a fluid array.

Below is what I have come up with but it returns "Warning: strpos(): needle is not a string or an integer". I cannot seem to get the array cases to work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

```
    $key = "results";
    $reportKey = array("base", "second", "third","latest");
    $keyArray = array();
    foreach($html->find('a') as $element){
        if (strpos($element->href, $key) !== false){
            if (strpos($element->href, $reportKey) !== false){
                $keyArray[] = $element->href;
            }
        }
    }
    echo "<pre>" . print_r($keyArray) . "</pre> ";
```

Comment: I guess you could try to make sure that an `<a>` does have an `href` attribute before trying to access it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strpos()` does not allow more than one needle, you can do this:

```
$key = "results";
$reportKey = array("base", "second", "third","latest");
$keyArray = array();

foreach($html->find('a') as $element)
{
    if (strpos($element->href, $key) !== false){
        if (
            strpos($element->href, $reportKey[0]) !== false
            || strpos($element->href, $reportKey[1]) !== false
            || strpos($element->href, $reportKey[2]) !== false
            || strpos($element->href, $reportKey[3]) !== false
         ){
             $keyArray[] = $element->href;
         }
     }
 }

 echo "<pre>" . print_r($keyArray) . "</pre> ";
```

You could also do your own function, this is only an example:

```
function multi_strpos($string, $check, $getResults = false)
{
$result = array();
  $check = (array) $check;

  foreach ($check as $s)
  {
    $pos = strpos($string, $s);

    if ($pos !== false)
    {
      if ($getResults)
      {
        $result[$s] = $pos;
      }
      else
      {
        return $pos;          
      }
    }
  }

  return empty($result) ? false : $result;
}
```

Comment: For my purposes, your first suggestion worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can't use an array as a needle in `strpos`. Change second `if` to:

```
if (str_replace($reportKey, "", $element->href) === $element->href) {
    $keyArray[] = $element->href;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution using [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php):

```php
$key = 'results';
$reportKey = ['base', 'second', 'third', 'latest'];
$keyArray = [];

foreach($html->find('a') as $element) {
    if (false !== strpos($element->href, $key)) {

        // I changed the condition here
        $pos = array_map(fn($k) => strpos($element->href, $k) !== false, $reportKey);

        if (in_array(true, $pos)){
            $keyArray[] = $element->href;
        }
    }
}
```

`$pos` will be an array containing **booleans** based on matches between `$element->href` and `$reportKey` items.
Then we check with `in_array()` if it matched at least one time.